# getting unicode error while decode packet recived on tcp socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

my python client is receiving packets from a c++ TCP socket which is acting as a server but when I try to decode the  I am getting UnicodeDecodeError:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 2: invalid continuation byte.

this is the packet : b'\x19\x00\xeb\x03NIFTY21JANFUT|1003.25\x19\x00\xeb\x03NIFTY21JANFUT|1003.25'

```
packet = b'\x19\x00\xeb\x03NIFTY21JANFUT|1003.25\x19\x00\xeb\x03NIFTY21JANFUT|1003.25'
print(packet)
print()

for i in packet:
    print(i)

packet.decode()
```

[click here for image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE1g0.png)

[click here for image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZWat.png)

Comment: But... why do you expect the byte string to contain UTF-8 data? What is it supposed to contain and how are you supposed to handle it? At first sight it contains some binary data and ASCII characters but nothing there let thing of UTF-8...

Comment: is there any way to decode bytes in python without using packet decode() method as by default there is "utf-8" set in the method  as c++ TCP server is not specifying any encoding while sending the packet

Comment: As the packet contains binary data, `struct` is probably more relevant here. But as you did not say how the packet was formatted I cannot help you more with that. IMHO converting everything into a string is a bad idea, but if you have to go that way, `Latin1` is a *universal* encoding for byte decoding: every byte is transformed into the unicode character of same code point.

Answer (score 0):

You should send data in `utf-8` encoding in c++ side, Unfortunately, I don't know how to set it correctly, but you can use `chardet` to detect encoding and decode packet respectfully

```
import chardet
packet_encoding = chardet.detect(packet)["encoding"]
decoded_packet = packet.decode(packet_encoding)
```

Comment: is there any way to decode bytes in python without using packet.decode() method as by default there is "utf-8" set in the method as c++ TCP server is not specifying any encoding while sending the packet –

Comment: Did you test the code? Could you show how you are getting packets from the socket?

Comment: getting this error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' . this is the packet i tried to decode b'\x19\x00\xeb\x03NIFTY21JANFUT|1003.25\x19\x00\xeb\x03NIFTY21JANFUT|1003.25'  would be great if u can decode it

Comment: this is the correct code: `decoded_result = packet.decode(result_encoding)`